# creating a efficient database schema

Tags: mysql, sqlite, schema

I have three tables

1. Main
2. TagIndex
3. Tag

Below are the schema of respective table

1. Main=UID[PK]|FILEPATH
2. TagIndex=UID|TID
3. Tag=TID|TAGNAME

I want to create a reference from **Main=TagIndex** via UID,reference from **TagIndex=Tab** via TID.My requirement is there would be multiple tagname to a particular UID but tagId would be unique.

```
Create Table Main(
    UID UNSIGNED BIG INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Filepath TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    FOREIGN KEY (UID) REFERENCES TagIndex(TID)
);

Create Table TagIndex(??)

Create Table Tag(??)
```

I am bugged up in how to create the schema.

Comment: What part of the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) do you not understand?

Comment: I understand the creation of tables and terminologies involved in sql.My main concern was how to fit this as per my requirement which I have explained above.Please refer EDIT1.